# What is the safest way to specify path to an html file in an express.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a directory structure where the `index.js` file is located at:

```
path/to/home-page/src/routes
```

Note this is also the `__dirname`. And the html file is located at:

```
path/to/home-page/public/bootstrap/Homepage/page.html
```

I am serving the `html` document by relative path via:

```
const html_rel_dir : String = "../../public/bootstrap/Homepage/"
...

index.get('/homepage', (req, res, next) => { 

    var path_to_html = path.join(__dirname, html_rel_dir, 'homepage.html')
    res.sendFile( path_to_html );

});
```

This smells "bad" to me in that the code will break if the directory structure changes, what is a better way to specify this?

Addendum, my app is configured so that public files are served via:

```
`this.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a View/Template engine can abstract the directory structure by letting you call out your view folder once at the top level. I use Nunjucks but its the same idea with the others. Handlebars, Mustache, etc. So my actual route calls look like this.

**general-pages.routes.js**

```
router.get('/feedback', function (req, res) {
  var data = getSomeData()

  res.render('general/feedback.html',data)
})
```

The framework early on in my main application was told the location of my views so from that point on it assumes any path is a subdirectory of my primary view folder. The one handler you see above handles lots of general pages. Then its referenced in my main app.js or whatever you call your main file like so:

```
app.use('/general',generalRoute)
```

So  anything for /general goes to the generalRoute handler general-pages.routes.js defined earlier. The full URL to the user is `/general/feedback`

**How does it know how to find my views?**

```
nunjucks.configure('views', {
  autoescape: true,
  express   : app
});
```

The code above says start looking for the folder called "views" inside the project folder. Its smart enough to use the internal node environment variables to determine the root directory. If you choose any of the other template engines they offer their own options for doing this.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using pug so I'm just doing `res.render('homepage', {})` in `index.ts`. Thank you again!